# golang http FormFile error "http: no such file"

Tags: vue.js, http, go

I try to write the web app with golang and vue.js.
On one of pages there is a form which sends uploaded files to server.

Page:

```
<template>
  <Container>
      <div class="content">
        <h1>
             Upload files
        </h1>
        <div class="forms">
            <FileForm v-bind:files="files['Model']" name="Model" v-on:upload="upload_model" v-on:submit="submit_model">
            </FileForm>
        </div>
      </div>
  </Container>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Container from '@/components/Container.vue'
import FileForm from '@/components/FileForm.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: function() {
    return {
        files: {},
    }
  },
  components: {
    Container,
    FileForm
  },
  methods: {
    upload_model: function(file) {
        this.files['Model'] = file
    },
    submit_model: function() {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Model', this.files['Model']);
        axios.put('http://' + document.location.host + '/api/upload_model', formData)
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    
  }
}
</script>
```

Form component:

```
<template>
    <div class="FileForm" v-bind:name="name">
        <label class="FileFormLabel">
            {{ name }}:
            <input type="file" files="files" v-on:change="fileUpload" v-bind:name="name"/>
        </label>
            <button class="SubmitBtn" v-on:click="submit">
                Submit
            </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'FileForm',
        props: ["value", "name"],
        data: function() {
            return {
                files: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            fileUpload: function(event) {
                this.$emit("upload", [event.target.files[0]])
            },
            submit: function() {
                this.files = []
                this.$emit("submit")
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

golang server:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
    "html/template"
//  "regexp"
//  "image/jpeg"
    "os"
//  "image"
//  "bytes"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)


var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
    "../frontend/upload.html"))

...

func api_upload_model(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
    
    r.ParseMultipartForm(50 << 20)
    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("Model")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Retrieving the File")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    ...
}

func main() {
    router := chi.NewRouter()
    router.Put("/api/upload_model", api_upload_model)
    ...
    fileServer = http.FileServer(http.Dir("../frontend/js"))
    router.Handle("/js/*", http.StripPrefix("/js/", fileServer))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

I use PUT request and I put 'Model' as name everywhere but what I got is:
Error Retrieving the File
http: no such file

What should I do to finally retrieve my file?

P.S.
Added

```
    fmt.Println("123")
    for key := range r.MultipartForm.File {
        fmt.Println("321")
        fmt.Println(key)
    }
```

And got
123
Error Retrieving the File
http: no such file

Does this mean that FormFile is empty? Why?!

P.P.S.

```
   fmt.Println(r.FormValue("Model"))
```

gives
[object File]
So, vue writes file not to FormFile but to FormValue?

P.P.P.S.
DumpRequest returns:

```
POST /api/upload_model HTTP/1.1
Host: XXX
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 183
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------3828442650922976093625228202
Dnt: 1
Origin: XXX
Referer: XXX
User-Agent: XXX

-----------------------------3828442650922976093625228202
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Model"

[object File]
-----------------------------3828442650922976093625228202--
```

And in browser request looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBdZD.png

Comment: `ParseMultipartForm` returns an error so you might want to check if that isn't `nil`. If that doesn't help clarify what the issue is, you can use `net/http/httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)` and print the output of that to see what the raw HTTP request that vue sent looks like. Keep in mind that the dump is a slice of bytes so make sure to first convert it to string before printing it.

Comment: And note that `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")` doesn't make sense unless what you want to do is to respond to the client with `multipart/form-data` type data in the response's body.

Comment: @mkopriva this is what DumpRequest returns:  
    POST /api/upload_model HTTP/1.1   
    Host: XXXXXX  
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*  
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5  
    Connection: keep-alive  
    Content-Length: 187  
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------273272501311553726862365981900  
    Dnt: 1  
    Origin: XXXXXX  
    Referer: XXXXXXX  
    User-Agent: XXXXXX

Comment: Please put it into the question (you can edit your question) and add some formatting to make it readable, thanks.

Comment: And do `DumpRequest` *before* parsing the body so that the dump includes the body content. If you do it afterwards then the body's "cursor" will be at EOF and the dump will *not* include the body's content, it will include only headers.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, edited the question with right placement of DumpRequest.

Comment: So the literal `[object File]` is of course not a valid file so I'm quite sure the problem is with the `vue.js` code that is sending the request rather than the Go code that is receiving it. I'm afraid I can't help any more than that because I am not familiar with vue.js, only a bit of Go is what I know.

Comment: @mkopriva you helped me to understand that the mistake is not in go-code. Thanks.